# I am not able to display image in Salesforce Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, richtextarea

I have created a rich text area field on the Product object. And try to display this image in Salesforce Site page. I am not able to do this.

I have something like this.

```
    <apex:outputText value="{!item.Product_Image__c}" escape="false"/>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? did you check field and object level security for this objects?

Comment: yes it is causing issue because of field level security for the site user.

Comment: is it resolved?